# Java rest api in android api 23 with httpurlconnection

Tags: java, android, web-services, rest, httpurlconnection

I have created a webservice in java

@Path("/app")
public class WebServiceApp {

```
MainClass mc = null;

@Path("/login")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public User authenticateLoginWebService(Login log){
    mc = new MainClass();
    return mc.authenticateLogin(log.getUsername(), log.getPassword());
}
```

}

This method has url: http://localhost:8080/webapi/api/app/login",

now to invoke this on android i have used following codes:

JSONParser:

```
public class JSONParser {

    String charset = "UTF-8";
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    DataOutputStream wr;
    StringBuilder result;
    URL urlObj;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    StringBuilder sbParams;
    String paramsString;

    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, JSONObject params) {
        if (method.equals("POST")) {
            try {
                urlObj = new URL(url);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/json");
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                conn.connect();

                OutputStream o = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(o, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(params.toString());
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                o.close();
                ***Log.e("Req code", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
                Log.e("Req Value", conn.getContent().toString())***;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (method.equals("GET")) {
            try {
                urlObj = new URL(url);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(false);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                conn.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            Log.e("Reader", reader.readLine());
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                result.append(line + "\n");
                Log.e("Line", line);
            }
            reader.close();
            Log.d("JSON Parser", "result: " + result.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        conn.disconnect();
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

LoginActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        final EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        TextView linkToSignup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.linktosignup);
        linkToSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent it = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class);
                startActivity(it);
                finish();
            }
        });


        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new HelperAsync().execute(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        TextView mainMenu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainMenu);
        mainMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent it = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HotelActivity.class);
                startActivity(it);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public class HelperAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, User>{

        @Override
        protected User doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                JSONObject inputParam = new JSONObject();
                inputParam.put("username", params[0]);
                inputParam.put("password", params[1]);
                Log.e("inpt",inputParam.toString());
                JSONObject obj = new JSONParser().makeHttpRequest("http://10.0.3.2:8080/webapi/api/app/login", "POST", inputParam);
                Log.e("jOsn", obj.toString());
                if (obj != null) {
                    try {
                        String username = obj.getString("username");
                        int phoneNumber = obj.getInt("phoneNumber");
                        String role = obj.getString("role");
                        String name = obj.getString("name");
                        Log.e("username", username + "         " + phoneNumber + "                " + role + "             " + name);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return null;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(User user) {
            super.onPostExecute(user);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
    }
}
```

i am getting request code `415` with error message as `Unsupported Media Type`.

also stacktrace is as follow:

```
05-03 00:40:16.256 1252-1829/com.whiteboard.aajkamenu W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.0.3.2:8080/webapi/api/app/login
05-03 00:40:16.260 1252-1829/com.whiteboard.aajkamenu W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
05-03 00:40:16.264 1252-1829/com.whiteboard.aajkamenu W/System.err:     at com.whiteboard.httpresource.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:77)
05-03 00:40:16.264 1252-1829/com.whiteboard.aajkamenu W/System.err:     at com.whiteboard.aajkamenu.LoginActivity$HelperAsync.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:71)
05-03 00:40:16.264 1252-1829/com.whiteboard.aajkamenu W/System.err:     at com.whiteboard.aajkamenu.LoginActivity$HelperAsync.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:62)
05-03 00:40:16.264 1252-1829/com.whiteboard.aajkamenu W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-03 00:40:16.264 1252-1829/com.whiteboard.aajkamenu W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-03 00:40:16.264 1252-1829/com.whiteboard.aajkamenu W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-03 00:40:16.264 1252-1829/com.whiteboard.aajkamenu W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-03 00:40:16.264 1252-1829/com.whiteboard.aajkamenu W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-03 00:40:16.264 1252-1829/com.whiteboard.aajkamenu W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-03 00:40:16.264 1252-1829/com.whiteboard.aajkamenu W/dalvikvm: threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d02b20)
05-03 00:40:16.272 1252-1829/com.whiteboard.aajkamenu E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
                                                                        Process: com.whiteboard.aajkamenu, PID: 1252
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                            at com.whiteboard.httpresource.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:91)
                                                                            at com.whiteboard.aajkamenu.LoginActivity$HelperAsync.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:71)
                                                                            at com.whiteboard.aajkamenu.LoginActivity$HelperAsync.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:62)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
05-03 00:40:16.280 546-813/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.whiteboard.aajkamenu/.LoginActivity
```

how to resolve this error?

Comment: Why not using a Http Library as [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) it's well documented and easy to use.

Comment: If it is possible without using any library i would like to do it in that way. Any error u can found in this code?

Comment: Could you describe what's in line 91 of JSONParser? As we don't have line number in here.

Comment: That's the line no. 91:       
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

Comment: Ok, So probably it's not been able to reach the endpoint: `http://localhost:8080/webapi/api/app/login` try to test it with some tool like [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com) to be sure that your been able to reach it. I think it isn't getting it cause of the `java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.0.3.2:8080/webapi/api/app/login` in the first line of your log.

Comment: Yes i already tried with postman, that's working fine

Comment: You'r closing the connection on `If("POST")` later you'r trying to get its inputStream. Try to close the connection just after you had done everything that you needed about this request.

Comment: I didnot close connection, i closed the streams

Comment: You're right. My bad. Sorry. I'll try later to try to discovery what is going wrong.

Comment: Have you checked the response in postman or hulrit?@Sarvesh

Comment: @CrazyAndroid yes i did, from postman. thats working fine

Comment: Have you included the permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />.You are testing the app in emulator or your device?@Sarvesh

Comment: @CrazyAndroid yes it included

Comment: You are testing the app in emulator or your device?@Sarvesh.

Comment: emulator! genymotion @CrazyAndroid

Comment: @CrazyAndroid this is a post url, i cannot use it in browser direcly i guess so

Comment: i am saying that this is a post method, and browser always request for a get method, we cannot use browser for post. isn't it?

Comment: I have modified your code slightly @Sarvesh.Please check if it is working for you.@Sarvesh.

Answer (score 1):

Please modify your doInBackground code in HelperAsync like this:

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args)
        {
         String login_url="http://localhost:8080/webapi/api/app/login";
         try {
                URL ur = new URL(login_url);
                 HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ur.openConnection();
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>;
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username, "Sarvesh"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "12345"));
        }
```

Comment: you moved the code from jsonparser to mainactivity is there any benifir? and please provide the further steps! after creating list, what to do?

Comment: No,I am not moving your code anywhere,I am suggesting that you should send your post request like the above code.After the request on your postExecute Toast a message thar your Login is successfull.@Sarvesh

Comment: As per my knowledge NameValuePair are in apache.http package which is removed

Comment: There is a shortcut method,which I use you can use Retrofit 2 library.The library is very easy to use and works very fast. @Sarvesh